# Header with 5 parts

Tags: html, css, header, split, zooming

I would like to create a HTML/CSS header with 5 parts.

1. Left (With 60% width)
2. EndLeft (Just a round end)
3. The logo
4. StartRight (Just a round start)
5. EndRight (To fill the rest of the header)

I have some problems with it.

At first my code:
http://jsbin.com/OFoTizO/1/edit

Whole view:
http://jsbin.com/OFoTizO/1

**Problems:**

1. If I zoom in, the divs are in a new line
2. If I zoom in, and I scroll to the right, the EndRight isn't filling out the whole website.

Comment: I think that you should read [this post](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/), it's really helpful for a deeper understanding of the positioning in HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a "min-width" is required. After setting a min-width, it worked without any problem